# MySQLdb.InterfaceError connecting through mysqlclient + SQLAlchemy, while ok connecting through the driver itself

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Having problem connecting to mysql db through mysqlclient (fork of MySQL-Python) + sqlalchemy as described here:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.mysqldb

My configuration: Windows10, PythonWin 3.10, mysqlclient 2.1.1, MySQL Community Server 8.0.31

Connecting through the driver itself, everything works fine:

```
import sqlalchemy
from MySQLdb import _mysql

dburl = sqlalchemy.engine.URL.create(drivername="mysql+mysqldb", username="xxx",
                                     password="xxx", host="localhost", port=33060,
                                     database="xxx_db")


db = _mysql.connect(dburl.host, dburl.username, dburl.password, dburl.database)
db.query('select * from test')
print(db.store_result())
```

resulting in `<_mysql.result object at 000001CE03780720>`
mysqld logs:

```
2022-10-20T07:09:16.157743Z    50 Connect   xxx@localhost on xxx_db using TCP/IP
2022-10-20T07:09:16.159751Z    50 Query select * from test
2022-10-20T07:09:16.833462Z    50 Quit
```

Then, connect whith the same `dburl` but through sqlalchemy:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(dburl)
engine.execute('select * from test')
```

resulting to `sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (MySQLdb.InterfaceError) (0, '')`
and the following in the mysqld logs:

```
2022-10-20T07:26:27.991626Z    55 Connect   
2022-10-20T07:26:27.991875Z    55 Quit
```

Clearly something wrong with mysql driver + sqlalchemy bundle, but I can't figure out where to dig? Extended logging seems to get nothing beyond the error above:

```
import logging, sys
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Can someone more experienced help, please? %)

**NEXT DAY UPDATE**
Here are some findings after I traced both cases during runtime:

the main difference is in the way the Connect method of the MySQLdb module is utilized:

- being used by the driver itself, the connection is initialized by passing authentication arguments as an `*args` tuple
- while sqlalchemy initialises connection using a `**kwargs` dictionary

So the sqlalchemy works after the following patch is added at the start of the Connect method of the MySQLlib module (`<pythondir>\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py`):

```
    if not len(args):
        args = tuple([kwargs.pop(k, '') for k in ['host', 'user', 'passwd', 'db']])
    kwargs.pop('port', None)
```

Yes, it is kind a hack, and is missing the possibility of defining a custom `port`, but - while it perfectly works as a temporary solution - I would greatly appreciate someone's help!